# how to point django website to python version besides default on centos

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, centos

I am using Centos and have installed python 2.7 so that I can run django 1.7.

I installed python 2.7 according to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4

The final installation step has me installing python using:

`make altinstall`  instead of: `make install`

So that it doesn't replace the default os version of python.

How do I use the new version of python 2.7 instead of the old version?

Since invoking `python` , by default goes to the old default version, my django app doesn't point to the new version.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to:

1. Install new python in any directory (e.g. `/opt`, `/home/<you>`, etc) that you're allowed to use (since you're on Centos, there should be a plenty of SELinux restrictions on executables...)
2. `virtualenv -p <path/to/fresh/python> <path/to/new/virtualenv/>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534343/2361497) the full discussion)